# it give me unsefined(NaN) in end_time so how can i resolve this

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jquery-ui

How can I get half an hour difference between start time and end time

```
$('#OutletEvents_start_time').datetimepicker({
    datepicker:false,
    format:'h:i a',
    step:30,
    onSelectTime: function() {
        var time1 = $(this).val().split(':');
        var endtime = parseInt(time1[0])+30;
        $('#OutletEvents_end_time').val(time1[1]+':'+endtime);
    }
});
```

Comment: From where you are getting time1 variable?

Comment: it give from OutletEvents_start_time

Answer (score 1):

`console.log` the `endtime` and `time1` variables. 
Make sure that `time1[0]` can be parsed to an int, that is where `NaN` is being returned.

You should also specify the radix in your `parseInt` call:

```
var endtime = parseInt(time1[0], 10) + 30;
```

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt):

> Always specify this parameter to eliminate reader confusion and to
>   guarantee predictable behavior. Different implementations produce
>   different results when a radix is not specified.